# Captivate Javascript detect LMS activity finished

Tags: javascript, moodle, scorm

I have a Captivate 8 project that has a web object with significant amounts of Javascript.

The web object sends data to the Moodle LMS via Captivates scorm driver. The Captivate web object opens up in a window or tab (depending on browser).

This mostly works, however when the activity is closed in the Moodle window the web object doesn't know this has happened and the web object window/tab remains open.

I need to pick up an event from the LMS that the student has 'exited the activity' via Captivate or the Scorm Driver Captivate uses (Rustici).
Or some other means of picking up a change.

I can't find anything obvious in the Captivate Javascript API or the Rustici Scorm Driver documentation.
Seems like something that should be obvious!

Has anyone already done this?

Answer (score 0):

I recall this issue but keep in mind this has a few years on it.  Essentially you can listen to events like unload, onbeforeunload to try and capture the fact the the content is being told to close it self out.

This gives you some opportunity to call your own internal exit method which should save the students attempt.

You can see some of how the SCOBot Content API performed that here - https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/blob/master/QUnit-Tests/js/scorm/SCOBot.js#L1978

GL

Comment: I think all I need to do is check if the Scorm Driver is available.
The driver is loaded by Captivate, if my javascript is running in it's own window it should see the driver go (become undefined) when Moodle shuts down the Captivate content. I can then just close the window.
I'll try it on Monday!

Comment: Technically if you are behaving at the LMS level you get a Terminate call if the content does its job correctly.  This isn't always the case, so it requires a little more status to recognize the fact we have a in-flight session, and a request for a new one.  At that point I start a 5-10 second window to give the content time to exit itself, or force it when that expires.  Every LMS will treat that differently or not at all.

Comment: I can't see anything in the Captivate JavaScript API documentation that looks like an event saying that the user has terminated or closed the content.
Same for the Rustici Scorm driver.

Comment: From what I can tell if the Scorm driver suddenly disappears, that implies the Captivate content has been closed.